# Turn off layout for a specific resource in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm looking for a way to configure a specific ActiveAdmin resource, so that all of its actions render without a layout, while the other resources keep the default layout. (The actions for that one resource are being rendered in AJAX dialogs, so I don't want the layout, just the main content.)

This didn't work:

```
controller do
  layout nil
end
```

I'm using 1.0.0. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe nil will work here. You'll want to use false. As in:

```
layout false
```

Comment: this does the same thing as `layout nil`

Answer (score 0):

according to [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render), You can also tell Rails to render with no layout at all:

```
controller do
  render layout: false
end
```

Comment: this raises a NoMethodError at startup: `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass` at `gems/actionview-5.0.2/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:212:in 'normalize_name'`

Comment: this probably can help https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11662#issuecomment-44742719

Answer (score 0):

### Quick way (no layout file, just your custom template):

If your model is named `Invoice` and you want a custom show template:

Place your custom template in `app/views/admin/invoices/show.html.erb` or `...html.arb`. For me, in ActiveAdmin 2.9, it overrides the entire ActiveAdmin layout.

### Slightly more complex way (with a custom layout file):

In `app/admin/invoices.rb`:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Invoice do
    ...
    controller do
        layout -> { action_name == 'show' ? 'invoice' : false }
    end
    ...
end
```

`action_name` is the Rails method that returns the current controller action. The above code will set the layout to `app/views/layouts/invoice.html.erb` (or one of the other supported Rails extensions).

Couldn't get `layout false` or even `layout 'somelayout'` to work with a `show do; ... end` block no matter what I tried.

Place your layout in `app/views/layouts/invoice.html.erb` or `...html.arb` or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

I think that defeats the purpose of using ActiveAdmin, whose primary function is to generate HTML views.  `layout false` won't work because ActievAdmin is providing it's own rendering layer on top of Rails ActionView.  What you can do is use ActiveAdmin and Rails API in combination, as discussed in [Charlie Gleason's popular blog](https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b).

Comment: I want the views, I just don't want the layout. I would like to use the generated form in a dialog.

Comment: I would still consider doing that (with Formtastic?) outside AA.  AA is using Arbre (ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base and Pages::Layout), not Rails ActionView for the layout.  Maybe the [CustomLayout](https://github.com/bys-control/activeadmin_custom_layout) plugin will help, but I've not used it.

Comment: I think if you want to have some actions that just return json within ActiveAdmin, we should be able to do that. I like opinonated systems, I hate overly opinonated ones forcing me to have to find work arounds. Just give me control over my systems and get out of the way. And I don't really care what others think about it. It's my system. So with that out of the way, I too want to skip layouts sometimes. Would love an easy way to choose and have that flexibility/power in the AA framework.

Comment: Downvoting an answer because it tries to explain to you the way things are instead of the way you want them to be is not going to earn you any sympathy from the maintainers. By all means file an issue on GitHub and see how far it gets you. I stand by my answer given as the most pragmatic response.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I love ActiveAdmin. I'm building a really quick billing app for myself with it. All I want is a view that renders, say, an invoice with a custom layout. I want everything else to use AA's layout. And well, there's a great candidate for a `show layout: false do; end` or a `render html: 'template', layout: false` type of feature! See my hackery above, which does work...